# How can I pull the top n rows of a list of tables with expanded columns?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I am using folder data source and would like to extract the first n rows from each file.

After implementing Excel.Workbook([Content]) to get the contents of each file and then expanding columns from each file, I would like to keep the contents of just the first n rows, rather than the entire columns.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On the Power Query editor, use the *Home > Keep Rows > Keep Top Rows* option to filter the list down to just 1 result. You can apply this at any step of the query based on how you want it filtered.

[image: Screenshot of menu option]

Answer (score 0):

I made some example data which looked like that
[image]
[image]
[image]

First I created a function with the name `fxXlContent` to extract the first two rows from one of these files which looks like that

```
(inpContent as any) =>
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(inpContent, null, true),
    Tabelle1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Tabelle1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    Header = Table.PromoteHeaders(Tabelle1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    changeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Header,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Info", type text}, {"Januar", Int64.Type}, {"Februar", Int64.Type}, {"März", Int64.Type}, {"April", Int64.Type}, {"Mai", Int64.Type}, {"Anmerkung", type text}}),
    keepFirstRows = Table.FirstN(changeType,2)
in
    keepFirstRows
```

Then I used this function when I extracted the folder to get the content of each file. You very likely need to adjust the steps below to your needs.

```
let
    Source = Folder.Files("d:\tmp\01"),
    filteredRows = Table.SelectRows(Source, each not Text.StartsWith([Extension], "~") and Text.EndsWith([Extension], "xlsx")),
    addCustomColumn = Table.AddColumn(filteredRows, "xlContent", each fxXlContent([Content])),
    removeOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(addCustomColumn,{"xlContent"}),
    extendXlCOntent = Table.ExpandTableColumn(removeOtherColumns, "xlContent", {"ID", "Info", "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Anmerkung"}, {"ID", "Info", "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Anmerkung"})
in
    extendXlCOntent
```

The single steps look like that
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]